# DDL doesn't work as expect inside Oracle block

Tags: oracle, plsql, ddl

I have a question about running ddl script in oracle block.

Basically I want to something for data migration. If a column has its data type changed, I want to create a temp column first, copy source column data to temp column, then drop source column, rename temp column to source, to finish migration process. But when I run the script below, it will only create a new temp column and copy data to the new column, but it will never run the last two alter table command. Can anyone figure out what the problem is? Thanks.

```
    create table t (a int);

    insert into t values(10);

    --change the data type from integer to varchar2(10);
    begin
      execute immediate 'alter table t modify a varchar2(10)';
    exception when others then
      begin
        execute immediate 'alter table t add b varchar2(10)';
        execute immediate 'update t set b = a';
        execute immediate 'alter tabe t drop column a';
        execute immediate 'alter table t rename column b to a';
      exception when others then
        dbms_output.put_line('cann''t change column a from integer to varchar2(10) due to error:' || sqlerrm);
      end;
    end;
    /
```

Answer (score 2):

You do see the drop column alter command has the typo "alter **tabe**...", right? If this is the code you're trying to run, as soon as it hits this statement you should see your error message, and your procedure only does the first two execute statements.

Comment: thanks DCookie, the thing is that I forgot to set serveroutput on so I thought every command is running without problem.

Comment: In that case you're better off without the exception handler ;-)